# Как игнорировать пустой блок?

Tags: php

```
<?php
  $html = '<p class="font_8" style="text-align:center; font-size:16px;"><span class="wixGuard">​</span><br />
&nbsp;</p>';

  $caption_dom = new DOMDocument;
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING); 
  $caption_dom->loadHTML($html);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  
  $tags_p = $caption_dom->getElementsByTagName('p'); 
  $data = $tags_p[0]->textContent;

  if(htmlentities($data) == null){
    exit; //надо попасть сюда!
  }
  //если не попали, проверяем
  $json = json_encode($data); 
  echo $json."<br \>";
?>
```

Получаю `\u00e2\u0080\u008b\n\u00a0` Почему? По сути перевод строки и пробел должен быть... Перевод строки там видно `\n`, а откуда всё остальное?

Цель: перевод строки и пробелы должны тримиться и хотел игнорить этот блок, как пустой, но пустой не выходит)

Пример из песочницы (с оригинальными данными): https://www.tehplayground.com/htWopS4E8F33ocCV

Comment: `\n\u00a0` - это переход и пробел `<br /> &nbsp;` а `<span class="wixGuard">​</span>` превращается в `\u00e2\u0080\u008b`

Comment: не хотите попробовать просто удалять?) с помощью str_replace

Comment: @АнтонСибгатулин а почему он превращается? span же не содержит текстовой информации... да и `\u00a0` c чего пробел? это же 10, а пробел 32. Просто удалять можно конечно, но не красиво и хотелось бы разобраться

Comment: откройте консоль браузера и сделайте вот так `var g = "\n\u00a0"` потом нажмите энтр,а затем введите g и нажмите enter

Comment: @АнтонСибгатулин это всё прекрасно, но на вопрос "почему" не отвечает) Что это за таблица кодировки такая, где u00a0 это пробел?

Comment: слушайте а у вас у самого какая кодировка на клавиатуре стоит?

Comment: немецкая, но это никак не связано с данной темой

Comment: посмотрите мой последний ответ :)

Comment: А зачем делать json_encode ? Собственно эта функция и превращает символы в коды вида \uNNNN

Comment: @newman исключительно, чтобы посмотреть что там на самом деле, иначе видим ´â  ´  и от этого не легче...

Comment: вы посмотрели мое последнее решение где я скинул фотку в чем была проблема?

Comment: @Isaev у вас там действительно в span есть какой-то символ, который здесь в тексте сообщения не виден, но в других редакторах он выводится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $html = str_replace("​","",$html);
```

Скопируйте и вставьте ,и он уберет этот символ :)

https://www.tehplayground.com/wf5xMczrZyzYxUmB
(P.S. 43 строка)

Comment: Это очень странно, но работает)

Comment: В программировании так всегда!

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код правильно работает

```
<?php
  $html = '<p class="font_8" style="text-align:center; font-size:16px;"><span class="wixGuard"></span><br/>&nbsp;</p>';

  $caption_dom = new DOMDocument;
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING); 
  $caption_dom->loadHTML($html);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  
  $tags_p = $caption_dom->getElementsByTagName('p'); 
  $data = $tags_p[0]->textContent;

  if(htmlentities($data) == null){
    exit; //надо попасть сюда!
  }
  //если не попали, проверяем
  $json = json_encode($data); 
  echo $json."<br \>";
  echo "some text: ".$data;
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

vs code подчеркнула мне эти уголочки ,я их стер и написал заново и всё заработало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

строка пустая (только пробел)

Comment: скопируйте и вставьте у себя мой код,он должен сработать,мне кажется это что то у вас с клавиатурой не то ,просто он подчеркнул только эти две скобочки,если бы была проблема с сайтом,то там были бы подсвечены все скобки

Comment: я добавил скрин в вопросе, нет там лишних символов в оригинале

Comment: Попробуйте заново скопировать оригинал и вставить в переменную $html без всяких исправлений (только удалите все \ и более ничего не стерайте) и всё заработает

Comment: это магия... этот символ откуда-то берется при копировании из хрома... вот кто-то тоже мучился https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055600/u200b-zero-width-space-characters-in-my-js-code-where-did-they-come-from

Comment: ладно, ничего не будем копировать, вот пример, который берет данные напрямую https://www.tehplayground.com/htWopS4E8F33ocCV

Comment: `value = value.replace(/([\/;:\)\]\}])/g, "$1\u200B");` надо функцию replaceAll в php реализовать та и всё

Comment: похоже да, эта вся гадость таки есть в оригинале (скинул в файл после загрузки и посмотрел), потому оно и копируется, т.ч. и textContent собирает нормально.